# How AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes really works and what it is for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

Here is a description (ASP.NET MVC 3):

1. I have this parameter `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes` in the default value `true` (checked with the debugger)
2. I have value-type field in my model (`int`, `DateTime`, `decimal`):

   ```
   public class MyModel
   {    
      public int SomeField { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. When I post *empty* form to this action (no `SomeField` specified):

   ```
     public ActionResult Submit(MyModel request)
     { 
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             ..
         }
     else
         {
             ..
         }
      }
   ```
4. I don't have any validation errors!  It seems to me logical -- the default value of int is `0`. Which is a value.

Questions:

If I want to force this value always expicitly set in request I should make it nullable and put `[Required]` on it, this works. But what `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes` is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we refer to ASP.NET MVC sources,  `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes` is checked only in [DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.Getvalidators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelvalidatorprovider.aspx) method which provides validation metadata for HTML Helpers (when rendering data-val-* attributes) and [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.aspx).

So, `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes` could be set when there is need to change behaviour of client-side validation and allow passing *empty values*(i.e. field is posted but has no value set) for value types to controller action.